# Reverse engineer an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I know that an array is essentially an object with the indexes as the keys, and the elements as the values, so I'm trying to reverse engineer an array with some methods as practice and learn since I'm new to JS and coding in general. I was able to recreate the following methods: push, pop, unshift, shift. Now my question is, is it possible to make it so that when I console log the object, it looks like an array rather than an object? I can't seem to figure it out without using an actual array and the push method. I would appreciate it if I could be led in the direction of the answer or given hints/things to look up and learn rather than a code answer. Also, any suggestion to improve the code I already written would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here's the object I created:

```js
function createArray() {
    let index = -1;
    const obj = {
        push: (...element) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                index++;
                obj[index] = element[i];
            }
        },
        pop: () => {
            let current = obj[index];
            delete obj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        shift: () => {
            let current = obj[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                obj[i] = obj[i + 1];
            }
            delete obj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        unshift: (...element) => {
            index += element.length;
            for (let i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (i >= element.length) obj[i] = obj[i - element.length];
                else obj[i] = element[i];
            }
            return index;
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

//test:
const array = createArray();
array.push(4, 5, 6, 7);
array.unshift(0, 1, 2, 3);
array.shift();
array.pop();

console.log(array);
```

Comment: An array equivelant of an object literal is an array of pairs: `Object.entries(obj)`

Comment: Please consider adding something like a `display` method as a prop on your `obj`. May be something like so: `display: () => (Object.values(obj).slice(0, index));`. And, try `console.log(array.display());`.

Comment: The `createArray` function appears to be a [JavaScript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). You may consider adding another variable (something to hold the values) & the `display` may simply return this new variable without the need to `.slice` to pick only until `index`.

Comment: @zer00ne I don't see how this is an answer to my question? (not saying this with an attitude, just genuinely asking).

Comment: @jsN00b this still requires another built in method to make the result look like an array for me under the hood. My question is if it's possible to somehow do it myself?

Comment: @R.Bair hence a comment, not an answer. Make a literal object then run `Object.entries(literalObject)` It'll look like this: `{propA: "A", propB: 1} => [ ["propA", "A"], ["propB", 1] ]` It's easier to work with and a method like `.flatMap()` makes use of 2D arrays intuitive (at least to me).

Comment: Trying to reinvent the wheel is ok for learning I suppose, maybe you need to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you need to avoid the `.slice`, it's simple. Just iterate from `0` to `index` and push the results to an array and return the array.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `class` ?

```js
class newArray {
    length = -1;
    array = {};
    constructor(){
    }

    push(...element) {
        for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            this.length++;
            this.array[this.length] = element[i];
        }
    }

    pop() {
        let current = this.array[this.length];
        delete this.array[this.length];
        this.length--;
        return current;
    }

    shift() {
        let current = this.array[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this.array[i] = this.array[i + 1];
        }
        delete this.array[this.length];
        this.length--;
        return current;
    }

    unshift(...element) {
        this.length += element.length;
        for (let i = this.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i >= element.length) this.array[i] = this.array[i - element.length];
            else this.array[i] = element[i];
        }
        return this.length;
    }
}

const array = new newArray();
array.push(4, 5, 6, 7);
array.unshift(0, 1, 2, 3);
array.shift();
array.pop();

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This still doesn't log as an array though. I want the result to look like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 0):

In the example below shows a literal object converted into an array of pairs:

```
{prop: 'A'} => [ ['prop', 'A'] ]
```

If you want to display something on the console in a practical way, use `JSON.stringify()`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Note in the example, there's a simple function that makes this process easier:

```
const log = data => JSON.stringify(data);
// Usage: log(data);
```

```js
const literalObject = {
  propA: "String",
  propB: 23,
  propC: [1, 'A', true],
  propD: {
    propE: 'B',
    propF: 5
  }
};

const arrayOfPairs = Object.entries(literalObject);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

log(arrayOfPairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet with the OP's expectation that the `console.log` needs to show only the elements of the array, a new `display` prop may be used as shown below:

```js
function createArray() {
    let index = -1;
    const obj = {
        push: (...element) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                index++;
                obj[index] = element[i];
            }
        },
        pop: () => {
            let current = obj[index];
            delete obj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        shift: () => {
            let current = obj[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                obj[i] = obj[i + 1];
            }
            delete obj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        unshift: (...element) => {
            index += element.length;
            for (let i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (i >= element.length) obj[i] = obj[i - element.length];
                else obj[i] = element[i];
            }
            return index;
        },
        display: () => {
          let result = [];
          for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) result.push(obj[i]);
          return result;
          // OR - if you like to avoid using 'result', try this:
          // return Object.values(obj).filter((o, i) => i < index);
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

//test:
const array = createArray();
array.push(4, 5, 6, 7);
array.unshift(0, 1, 2, 3);
array.shift();
array.pop();

console.log(array.display());
```

Rather than holding the actual array-data in the same `obj` that is being used to hold the methods, it may be better to use a dedicated variable within the `closure` to hold the elements.

```js
function createArray() {
    let index = -1;
    let itemsObj = {};  // new variable to hold the elements
    const obj = {
        push: (...element) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                index++;
                itemsObj[index] = element[i];
            }
        },
        pop: () => {
            let current = itemsObj[index];
            delete itemsObj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        shift: () => {
            let current = itemsObj[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                itemsObj[i] = itemsObj[i + 1];
            }
            delete itemsObj[index];
            index--;
            return current;
        },
        unshift: (...element) => {
            index += element.length;
            for (let i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (i >= element.length) itemsObj[i] = itemsObj[i - element.length];
                else itemsObj[i] = element[i];
            }
            return index;
        },
        // new method 'display' to get the elements to be shown like an array
        display: () => (Object.values(itemsObj))
    }
    return obj;
};

//test:
const array = createArray();
array.push(4, 5, 6, 7);
array.unshift(0, 1, 2, 3);
array.shift();
array.pop();

console.log(array.display());
```

**Reference**:

The above snippets use [JavaScript `closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

How something is printed on the console is entirely up to the console.

The closest thing you can get is to override `toString` and leverage string concatenation:

```
...
toString: () => "[your representation here]"
...

console.log("My array: " + array);
```

That prints *My array: [your representation here]*

How does it work? When you concatenate (+) a string with an object then the `toString` method of that object is called.